# how should I start please?

Tags: theory, piano, beginner

I am still new to music and all this stuff. I have an electric keyboard. I can play some simple songs on it but I still don't know much. So how should I start??!!

Answer (score 1):

Far and away the best way to start is to find a good local piano or keyboard teacher who can guide and instruct you. They can give you far better guidance and instruction than anything you can get from this forum, YouTube videos or books.